# CUDA 6D for loop computation

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to parallelize the following 6D nested for loop in CUDA (Pascal architecture).

```cpp
const int NX = 250, NY = 250, NZ = 250, NA = 100, NB = 100, NC = 100;
float data_out[NX * NY * NZ];
float data_in[NA * NB * NC];
float datax[NX];
float datay[NY];
float dataz[NZ];

for (int ix = 0; ix < Nx; ix++)
{
    for (int iy = 0; iy < Ny; iy++)
    {
        for (int iz = 0; iz < Nz; iz++)
        {
            float result = 0.0f;
            for (int ia = 0; ia < NA; ia++)
            {
                for (int ib = 0; ib < NB; ib++)
                {
                    for (int ic = 0; ic < NC; ic++)
                    {
                        // some exemplary computation (see kernel)
                    }
                }
            }
            data_out[iz + iy * NZ + ix * (NZ * NY)] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I implemented a kernel that performs the inner 3D nested for loop (loop variable `ia`, `ib`, `ic`), i.e., I don't use parallel reduction so far. Therefore, each kernel computes the sum of `NA * NB * NC = 1000000` values.

**EDIT:** The computation in the for loop was updated to account for any nonlinear combination of the values, i.e., the values cannot be computed outside the for loop

```cpp
__global__ void testKernel
(
    float *data_out,
    const float *data_in,
    const float *datax,
    const float *datay,
    const float *dataz,
    const int NX,
    const int NY,
    const int NZ,
    const int NA,
    const int NB,
    const int NC
)
{
    int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
    int iz = threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z*blockDim.z;

    if (ix >= NX || iy >= NY || iz >= NZ)
        return;

    float3 xyz = make_float3(datax[ix], datay[iy], dataz[iz]);
    float result = 0.0f;
    for (int ia = 0; ia < NA; ia++)
    {
        for (int ib = 0; ib < NB; ib++)
        {
            for (int ic = 0; ic < NC; ic++)
            {
                // some exemplary nonlinear computation to show memory access
                result += nonlinear_combination(data_in[ic + ib * NC + ia * (NC * NB)], xyz, ia, ib, ic);
            }
        }
    }
    data_out[iz + iy * NZ + ix * (NZ * NY)] = result;
}

int main()
{
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    const int NX = 250, NY = 250, NZ = 250, NA = 100, NB = 100, NC = 100;

    float *d_data_out, *d_data_in, *d_datax, *d_datay, *d_dataz;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data_out, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data_in, NA * NB * NC * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_datax, NX * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_datay, NY * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dataz, NZ * sizeof(float));

    dim3 blockSize(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 gridSize(128, 128, 64);

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    testKernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_data_out, d_data_in, d_datax, d_datay, d_dataz, NX, NY, NZ, NA, NB, NC);
    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float milliseconds = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("Elapsed time: %.2f ms\n", milliseconds);

    cudaFree(d_data_out);
    cudaFree(d_data_in);
    cudaFree(d_datax);
    cudaFree(d_datay);
    cudaFree(d_dataz);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any benefit of parallelizing the inner for loop as well using parallel reduction, as the total number of iterations of the outer for loop (`NX * NY * NZ = 15625000`) is already higher than the total number of parallel threads?

Also, how can I optimize the memory access? It might be beneficial to ensure that each thread in a block is accessing the same portion of the data and copy this portion of the data to the shared memory, right?

Comment: Memory reads are expensive. In your loop you are unnecessarily reading `datam[]` many times, when it does not change .

Comment: @AnderBiguri How can I prevent the memory reads? I always access a different index, so I'm unsure how to get rid of the memory reads.

Comment: You could split this into two very basic operations by factoring out  `datax[ix] + datay[iy] + dataz[iz]`. I.e. the first operation is a complete reduction of `data_in` and the second operation is calculating `datax[ix] + datay[iy] + dataz[iz]` and scaling it by the result of the reduction. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: To then optimize the second operation, you could cooperatively load the needed tiles of `datax`, `datay` and `dataz` into shared memory, so all accesses to global memory are coalesced.

Comment: @brnk in the cuda code, just get the `(datax[ix] + datay[iy] + dataz[iz])` out of the three loops? you are running that line 100^3 times, instead of 1.

Comment: @AnderBiguri that is probably done by the compiler.

Comment: @paleonix fair assumption, but I tend to not let my code be subjected of what "probably" the compiler does. Plus, I don't know how sophisticated the compiler is, as far as I understand, unless those variables are defined as constant, the compiler can't make the assumption that they are not changed while the loop is going.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I mean I would make it explicit as well, it's just very minor compared to the ways one really can cut down the number of accesses as mentioned by me.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I chose a wrong exemplary computation. I updated the kernel to account for any nonlinear combination of the values, i.e., parts of the computation cannot be performed outside the for loop. However, can I use shared memory for `data_in`?

Comment: You should still certainly use it for `datax`, `datay` and `dataz` in the beginning. For `data_in` I'm not sure if it will speed things up, but if you want to try, you will need to add additional loops for tiling (complete `data_in` doesn't fit into shared memory).

Comment: The difficult thing for `data_in` will be to figure out the ideal tile size. Bigger tiles take more shared memory which could negatively impact occupancy. Smaller tiles will mean more frequent block-wide synchronization. I think the minimal tile size should be 1024B as that is the size of a cache line if I remember right.

Comment: As you said the amount of parallelism is already big enough for Pascal (probably even for Ampere and Hopper). So I wouldn't think that implementing parallel reductions will benefit performance. If you want to try either way, you could use one warp per reduction, so the communication can be done via warp shuffles.

Answer (score 1):

Generally your approach looks right. 15625000 threads is very much, even for latest GPUs with 10000 cores. For them about 250000 threads is desirable. Although your blocks-threads division will waste a lot of runned threads. Because 128 threads by x * 8 blocks by x = 1024 and much less than NX = 250. And so on.

And also CUDA would not allow you to run more than 1024 threads in one block. You can use block size like (NX, 1, 1) and grid size - like (1, NY, NZ), to economize some computations. Only it's desirable block thread size would be divisible by 32.

For coalesced memory access be sure that neighbour threads access neighbour memory cells and (desirably) the block is aligned to (about) 64 bytes. Fastest changing index of threads is x, so for example in the first warp threads will have y and z = 0 and x = 0, ... 31.

You did right by summing in local variable and writing result only once.

As to reducing number of threads, this can economize your threads initializations. 15625000 executions of block  int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x; and below or less. Since your inner 3D loop is huge, this promises very small gain.

And yes, some additional regrouping of computations can make possible not to read your data_in array so much times. Look at classic matrix multiplications on GPU example.

I would also try loops unrolling. After ensuring coalesced and minimal memory access of course (but maybe you will not need shared memory since GPU will use SMs memory as cache automatically). After getting first working version you will be able to get many insights about effectiveness of your code with NSight Compute.

Comment: As I'm quite new to CUDA, I do not know how to check if neighbour threads access neighbour memory cells. Is there any kind of profiler to check if this is satisfied? Or is there any approach on how to check it directly in the code?

Comment: On first stages the best solution is to think thoughtfully. After the code works Nsight Compute can detects such thing. Do not remember about division by lines of source codes, but it for sure can count share memory requests and excessive accesses for a kernel. And also you use CUDA debugger (cuda-gdb or Nsight Visual Studio Edition) and display for all threads of current stopped warp addresses they are trying to access

Comment: @brnk If you don't know "coalescing" yet, [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/) blog post might be a good first read. There is also a section in the [Best Practices Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) from the docs.